# What are the requirements to obtain an FAA private pilot's license in Bosnia?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, ppl

I'm a US citizen currently living in Bosnia. Before I left the states, I was working on getting my PPL.

I currently have about 65 hours and was very close to finishing, but I was unable to do so before I left because of inclement weather and preparing for the move.

Would I be able to finish getting my license in Bosnia?

Are flight requirements the same? Would the flight hours transfer?

If I complete my license here would it be valid in the states?

Comment: You would have to get a Bosnian license and then transfer it to the FAA. So first you need to figure out what it takes to get a license in Bosnia.

Comment: You might check if it's cheaper/easier to come back to the US for a break, finish your US certificate, then go back to Bosnia and convert or validate it to fly there. And before you commit to a Bosnian license, consider if you'll have to maintain/renew it regularly and what your long-term plans are. FAA licenses never expire, which is a huge plus.

Comment: @Pondlife That was my first thought as well.

Comment: Your largest obstacle would be finding a FAA CFI and a FAA Flight Examiner in Bosnia.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to find a US-licensed CFI in Bosnia to give you the training, and then a Designated Examiner in Bosnia to give you the oral and practical exams. The first may be doable, the second pretty much impossible unless you want to pay someone to come to Bosnia. Certainly it would be much easier (and probably cheaper) to come back to the US for a few weeks and do nothing but finish your ticket.